# what's `auto classMemberFunction()->void {}` signature?

Tags: c++, signature, auto

I've seen in [an article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616090/Delegates-Cplusplus-vs-Impossibly-Fast-A-Quick-a) a code similar to this one:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:

  auto myFunction(int i)->void {
    std::cout << "Argument is " << i << std::endl;
  }
};

void main() {
  MyClass myClass;
  myClass.myFunction(4);
}
```

The program prints correctly the output **Argument is 4**, but I don't understand the signature of the class function member and what's its difference with the usual one. When it's useful to use this different signature rather than `void myFunction(int i)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an (ab)use of the trailing-return-type syntax that has been introduced in C++11. The syntax is:

```
auto functionName(params) -> returnType;
auto functionName(params) -> returnType { }
```

It works the same as a classic function declaration with the return type on the left, except that the trailing type can use names introduced by the function's signature, i.e:

```
T    Class::function(param);      // No particular behaviour
auto Class::function(param) -> T; // T can use Class::Foo as Foo, decltype(param), etc.
```

In this case though, there is no point except consistency.

Comment: Can consistency really be called abuse? (I mean if at least one function actually requires it)

Comment: @StoryTeller your question mark is what called for the parentheses. It's a matter of taste -- I personally find the trailing type syntax harder to read, but I certainly see why it can be compelling.